Apache OpenOffice 4.1.15 configure: error: only sparc and i386 processors are supported when running configure script
I am trying to compile Apache Open Office 4.1.15 from source because I can't find a precompiled package for Solaris 10. I am running Solaris 10 x86. I am following the readme instructions in main. I first run autoconf to generate the configure file, then I run the configure file with its configure switches, though I have stopped using any switches for now because it's just extra words and doesn't affect the outcome currently. My processor is just an Intel Pentium Dual-Core E5700 @ 3GHz. I've tried searching for the error but I've come up empty handed, I don't have much experience with building software from source.
Here is the terminal output:
Script started on Sat Nov 16 21:50:48 2024
# autoconf
# ./configure
checking whether configure is up-to-date... yes
********************************************************************
*                                                                  *
*   Apache OpenOffice build configuration.                         *
*                                                                  *
*   The configure process checks your platform to see whether      *
*   you can build Apache OpenOffice on it.                         *
*   This process checks all pre-requisites and generates a file    *
*   containing the necessary environment variables.                *
*   Source this file after configure has ended successfully.       *
*                                                                  *
*   Warnings that are generated during the configure process       *
*   must be taken into account since it can be a reason for        *
*   an unsuccessful build of Apache OpenOffice.                    *
*                                                                  *
********************************************************************

********************************************************************
*                                                                  *
*   Checking the platform pre-requisites.                          *
*                                                                  *
********************************************************************

checking for grep that handles long lines and -e... /usr/xpg4/bin/grep
checking for egrep... /usr/xpg4/bin/grep -E
checking for gawk... gawk
checking for gawk... /opt/csw/bin/gawk
checking for sed... /usr/bin/sed
checking for solenv environment... default
checking for custom pack.lst... no
checking build system type... x86_64-pc-solaris2.10
checking host system type... x86_64-pc-solaris2.10
checking target system type... x86_64-pc-solaris2.10
/etc/*-release: No such file or directory
SunOS dhcp-137-112-128-64 5.10 Generic_147148-26 i86pc i386 i86pc
checking for gtar... /usr/sfw/bin/gtar
checking the Solaris operating system release... ok (10)
checking the processor type... configure: error: only sparc and i386 processors are supported
# exit

script done on Sat Nov 16 21:51:04 2024

